# How to print multiline strings on the same line in Python

Tags: python

In the program I'm working on I need to have 3 multiline strings print out next to each other, so the first line of each string is on the same line, the second line of each string is on the same line, etc.

Input:

```
    '''string
    one'''
    '''string
    two'''
    '''string
    three'''
```

Output:

```
    string
    one
    string
    two
    string
    three
```

Desired result:

```
     stringstringstring
     one   two   three
```

Comment: Please, post an `expected result`

Answer (score 4):

Why not a very convoluted one liner?

Assuming `strings` is your list of multiline strings:

```
strings = ['string\none', 'string\ntwo', 'string\nthree']
```

You can do this with Python 3s print function:

```
print(*[''.join(x) for x in zip(*[[x.ljust(len(max(s.split('\n'), key=len))) for x in s.split('\n')] for s in strings])], sep='\n')
```

This works for strings with more than 2 lines (all strings must have the same number of lines or change `zip` to `itertools.izip_longest`)

Answer (score 3):

Not a one-liner...

```
# Initialise some ASCII art
# For this example, the strings have to have the same number of
# lines.
strings = [
'''
  _____
 /    /\\
/____/  \\
\\    \  /
 \\____\/
'''
] * 3

# Split each multiline string by newline
strings_by_column = [s.split('\n') for s in strings]

# Group the split strings by line
# In this example, all strings are the same, so for each line we
# will have three copies of the same string.
strings_by_line = zip(*strings_by_column)

# Work out how much space we will need for the longest line of
# each multiline string
max_length_by_column = [
    max([len(s) for s in col_strings])
    for col_strings in strings_by_column
]

for parts in strings_by_line:
    # Pad strings in each column so they are the same length
    padded_strings = [
        parts[i].ljust(max_length_by_column[i])
        for i in range(len(parts))
    ]
    print(''.join(padded_strings))
```

Output:

```
  _____    _____    _____  
 /    /\  /    /\  /    /\ 
/____/  \/____/  \/____/  \
\    \  /\    \  /\    \  /
 \____\/  \____\/  \____\/
```

Comment: I like how this is close to my code but well explained. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
s = """
you can

    print this

string
"""

print(s)
```

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear enough. What my problem is is that I have ascii art stored in different items in a list, and I need to have those items printed out next to each other.

Comment: Wow, you should edit your question then... have you tried `.split()` and `''.join()` ? Is your input a `list` with strings?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
strings = [x.split() for x in [a, b, c]]
just = max([len(x[0]) for x in strings])
for string in strings: print string[0].ljust(just),
print
for string in strings: print string[1].ljust(just),
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is closer to me.

```
first_str = '''string
one'''
second_str = '''  string
  two  '''
third_str = '''string
three'''

str_arr = [first_str, second_str, third_str]
parts = [s.split('\n') for s in str_arr]
f_list = [""] * len(parts[0])
for p in parts:
    for j in range(len(p)):
        current = p[j] if p[j] != "" else "   "
        f_list[j] = f_list[j] + current

print('\n'.join(f_list))
```

Output:

```
string  stringstring
one  two  three
```