# please fix my python code which is print out function

Tags: python, printing

I tried to create code which is print out last 2 digit number but print out with star shape

this is my code, I want print out last 2 digit within shapes

```
### number 1 shape with star mark ###

def one():
    x_str = "";
    for row in range (0,6):
        for col in range(0,6):
            if(col==3 and row>0) or (row==2 and col==2):
                x_str = x_str + "*"
            else:
                x_str = x_str + " "
        x_str = x_str + "\n"
    return x_str

### number 2 shape with star mark ###
def two():
    x_str = "";
    for row in range (0,6):
        for col in range(0,6):
            if(col==4 and row>1 and row<3) or (col==2 and row>3 and row<5) or (row==1 and col>1 and col<5) or (row==3 and col>1 and col<5) or (row==5 and col>1 and col<5):
                x_str = x_str + "*"
            else:
                x_str = x_str + " "
        x_str = x_str + "\n"
    return x_str

###  number 3 shape with star mark ###
def three():
    x_str = "";
    for row in range (0,6):
        for col in range(0,6):
            if(col==4 and row>1 and row<3) or (col==4 and row>3 and row<5) or (row==1 and col>1 and col<5) or (row==3 and col>1 and col<5) or (row==5 and col>1 and col<5):
                x_str = x_str + "*"
            else:
                x_str = x_str + " "
        x_str = x_str + "\n"
    return x_str

###  number 4 shape with star mark ###
def four():
    x_str = "";
    for row in range (0,6):
        for col in range(0,6):
            if(col==4 and row>0) or (col==2 and row>0 and row<4) or (col==3 and row==3):
                x_str = x_str + "*"
            else:
                x_str = x_str + " "
        x_str = x_str + "\n"
    return x_str

### main code ###
shapes = {'1':one(),'2':two(),'3':three(),'4':four()}
x = words[-2:]

while True:
    words = input("please enter 8digit number between 1 to 4")
    output = "".join([shapes[number] for number in x if number in shapes])
    if output:
        print("Your number is" +words+ ",the last two-digit number is:")
        print(output, end='\r')

    elif words == "QUIT":
        break
    else:
        print("Error: invalid words please try again")
```

I tried to make code but it doesn't work properly.

could you guys edit my code to working properly?

thanks a lot guys.

Comment: `x = words[-2:]` should be *after* you assign `words`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
### number 1 shape with star mark ###

def one():
    x_str = "";
    for row in range (0,6):
        for col in range(0,6):
            if(col==3 and row>0) or (row==2 and col==2):
                x_str = x_str + "*"
            else:
                x_str = x_str + " "
        x_str = x_str + "\n"
    return x_str

### number 2 shape with star mark ###
def two():
    x_str = "";
    for row in range (0,6):
        for col in range(0,6):
            if(col==4 and row>1 and row<3) or (col==2 and row>3 and row<5) or (row==1 and col>1 and col<5) or (row==3 and col>1 and col<5) or (row==5 and col>1 and col<5):
                x_str = x_str + "*"
            else:
                x_str = x_str + " "
        x_str = x_str + "\n"
    return x_str

###  number 3 shape with star mark ###
def three():
    x_str = "";
    for row in range (0,6):
        for col in range(0,6):
            if(col==4 and row>1 and row<3) or (col==4 and row>3 and row<5) or (row==1 and col>1 and col<5) or (row==3 and col>1 and col<5) or (row==5 and col>1 and col<5):
                x_str = x_str + "*"
            else:
                x_str = x_str + " "
        x_str = x_str + "\n"
    return x_str

###  number 4 shape with star mark ###
def four():
    x_str = ""
    for row in range(0, 6):
        for col in range(0, 6):
            if(col==4 and row> 0) or (col==2 and row>0 and row<4) or (col==3 and row==3):
                x_str = x_str + "*"
            else:
                x_str = x_str + " "
        x_str = x_str + "\n"
    return x_str

### main code ###
shapes = {'1':one(),'2':two(),'3':three(),'4':four()}

while True:
    words = input("please enter 8digit number between 1 to 4")
    output = "".join([shapes[number] for number in words[-2:] if number in shapes])
    if output:
        print("Your number is" +words[-2:]+ ",the last two-digit number is:")
        print(output, end='\r')
    elif words == "QUIT":
        break
    else:
        print("Error: invalid words please try again")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have one more short question. if I enter "12341234" will print out 3 and 4 with shape but it is print out with different line. how can I print in a same line. ex) currently printed 3(at line 1) 4(at line2) --> want change to 3 4(at line 1)

Comment: If I helped you, please accept my answer :)  I don't know of I understood your question as well. But maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372078/how-to-print-multiline-strings-on-the-same-line-in-python .